# How to solve this simple linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

I have the following equation (I personally wrote)

$2x + (5+3) = 46 + 3x$

Is the above equation possible at all? If yes, how to solve it?

I am new to math, as a free-learner (not associated with my academic major), if the right hand of the equation was minus $(-)$ instead of plus $(+)$, I could go with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Felt like this was too short for an answer. We have that $2x+(5+3)=2x+8=46+3x$ so that subtracting $2x$, $2x+8-2x=46+3x-2x$ which is the same as $2x-2x+8=(3-2)x+46$ or $8=x+46$ or thus subtracting $46$, $x=-38$.

Comment: Subtract $2x$ from both sides of the equations. Then subtract $46$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be scared of negative numbers.

1st step: Get rid of the parenthesis

$2x+5+3=46+3x$

2nd step: Get all x on the left hand and all numbers on the right hand:

$2x-3x=46-5-3$

3rd step: do the math:

$-1x=38$

4th step: divide both sides with the factor of x (-1):

$\frac{-1x}{-1}=\frac{38}{-1}$

5th step: Get your result:

$x=-38$

Comment: Would you please edit your question with an added explanation from step 4 to 5? Thanks so much.

Comment: You have -1x=something. So in order to get x you should divide both sides with -1. If you had 3x=24 you would have to divide both sides by 3. so you would get x=24/3. x=8

Comment: Ow...very much thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

[**The Euclid way**](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/cn.html)

> 1. Things which equal the same thing also equal one another.
> 2. If equals are added to equals, then the wholes are equal.
> 3. If equals are subtracted from equals, then the remainders are equal.
> 4. Things which coincide with one another equal one another.
> 5. The whole is greater than the part.

---

$$\begin{array}{rcl}2x+(5+3)-2x-46&=&46+3x-2x-46\\-38&=&x \end{array}$$

Comment: @MostafaTalebi, they are not tips. Click on the link to know more.

Comment: OK I meant rules